# installing SciPy with PyPy on Windows

Tags: python, scipy, pypy

I am trying to install SciPy with PyPy on Windows. I installed PyPy with the windows 32-bit zip on the website. I installed numpy using `python setup.py install`. I tried to install scipy with `pip install scipy` or related commands, I always get a "NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found" error. Note I cannot install with wheels because they are meant for CPython 2.7 not PyPy 2.7

How can I solve this problem, especially since most of SciPy is compatible with PyPy?

Comment: If there are no wheels out for you, your are in big trouble. Installing scipy from source on windows is pretty hard. If you are that crazy to tackle it: visit scipy's install docs and maybe check out some windows-based CI-scripts within scipy's project (assuming pypy is not known to be incompatible beforehand).

Comment: @sascha well it's known to be compatible with PyPy, though maybe not for Windows, that I am not sure. I did install numpy so idk scipy doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you'll need to install a BLAS+LAPACK library.

The build instructions for Scipy on CPython https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/windows.html probably are applicable here, but precisely what you need to do depends on what compiler you used for Pypy.

Comment: The link unfortunately no longer works.